# Excel: Find first value in column 2x current value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet. I have column C which has price values. In column D, I have the date. In column E, I want to return the first time the current price reaches is doubled.

[image: Image of what I need]

So for example, if C1 is $1 and the first time column C gets to $2 is C27, then  I would want to return the date of E27 to E1. Note that the range lookup has to change. For instance, for C2, we don't want to look at C1 to see if the price is doubled. Basically, we cannot go back in time. Can anyone help with this? I tried using vlookup, but it is not working as I would like. It seems like its missing some values because it isn't exactly 2x.

Comment: Your example starts in C2 not C1 but your verbiage says C1, which is it?

Comment: Also why does E4 not return 5 also as it is also 2 times greater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($C1:$C$100)/($C1*2<=$C1:$C$100),1)),"Does not Double")
```

Note that all the references to `$C1` have the row as relative as we only want to look down from the row where the formula is placed.  If it does not double in the allotted area then it will return `Does not Double`

[image]

Comment: Hmm I get #NUM. I updated the question to be more clear. If C1 is $1 and the first time a value in column C gets to $2 is C27, then E1 would return the date in D27. Does this make sense? We also cannot look back in time. So if the price in C1 is 2x that of C2 I don't care. I only look in the future for this.

Comment: Just added an image so you can see what I mean

Comment: See edit, it works for me.

Comment: Nice! Are you sure it doesn't look back in time? It only looks forward from each cell? What part of the code does this?

Comment: @jackson I stated the reason in the answer.  The `$C1` will change to the row as it is dragged down and as such will only look at the range from that row down.

Comment: How come if I want to see 50% loss, it does not work? If I put in 0.5, it does not work the same. It only works for numbers > 1

Comment: why does it not work for losses? It only works for numbers greater than 1

Comment: That is because 2 times a negative is a smaller negative number and the inequality will not find it.

Comment: what? I changed it from 2x to 0.5x. How can I make this work?